# Public Array Compile Error - Can't assign to array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compiler-errors

When I want to populate a public array, it throws this error:

```
Option Explicit

Public myArray(5) As Variant

Sub addToArray()
    myArray() = Array(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
End Sub
```

It gives me a "Compile error: Can't assign to array" error:

[image]

Anyone an idea what might went wrong?
This is just a short array. I might make it way bigger. Defining each value separately is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare as variant without size (for the array)

```
Public myArray() As Variant
```

to be able to use it like

```
myArray = Array(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```