# VB6 Split string into an array Error "Can't assign into array" compile error

Tags: arrays, vb6

I am trying to split a string into an array in VB6.

The string is stored in a database and looks like this:

> "By Value : "

Sometimes it may include something more at the end after the colon, this is why I want to split it as I am comparing it in an if statement, as shown below.

Overall my code goes like this:

```
Dim deliveryType(2) As String

deliveryType = Split(vaGoodsInLine.FieldValue("Comment"), ":")

If deliveryType(0) = "By Value " Then
 'Do Something
End IF
```

I am getting the following error

[image]

I also tried defining the array as a variant with no size like this:

```
Public deliveryType() As Variant
```

But then I get this error
[image: deliveryType]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Public Array Compile Error - Can't assign to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471511/public-array-compile-error-cant-assign-to-array)

Comment: @GSerg unfortunately not, I am getting a Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Comment: If you have redeclared `deliveryType` as Variant, then you should have not done that. You should have [removed the fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460458/is-it-possible-to-assign-values-to-array-without-looping-vba#comment120991520_68460458).

Comment: So many errors here.  This is only the beginning.

Comment: Don't set the size on the array...  `Dim deliveryType(2) As String` should just be `Dim deliveryType() As String`.  Then, the original should be fine.  For the second, you could try `Dim deliveryType As Variant`, without `()`s, as Variant can already accept both arrays and non arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim deliveryType() As String
deliveryType = Split(vaGoodsInLine.FieldValue("Comment"), ":")
Dim deliveryTypeValue As String

If Not UBound(deliveryType) = 0 Then
    deliveryTypeValue = NullStr(deliveryType(0))
End If
    
If deliveryTypeValue = "By Value" Then
    'Do Something
End IF
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Did your first 2 lines get combined into one?